# Запуск копий приложения без группировки на панели задач

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как правильно реализовать запуск EXE файла из моего приложения с отключенной группировкой на панели задач его копий?

Сейчас использую такой код, но с ним все копии группируются:

```
string file = Path.Combine("C:/test/", "test.exe");
if (!File.Exists(file))
{
    MessageBox.Show("File not found!");
    return;
}

try
{
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = file,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    Process.Start(processStartInfo);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Группировка это фича самой ос, кликнув правой мышой по группе, можно группу разгруппировать. Вот надо как то узнать как она это делает.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь делает она это скорее всего по GUID приложения.

Comment: Собственно про GUID для COM я знаю, а вот для приложений не слышал.

Comment: Мне кажется, группируются приложения, запущенные из одного exe, значит чтобы приложения не группировались — они должны быть запущенны из разных файлов. Итого решение — копируем exe с новым рандомным именем и запускаем его

Comment: @АндрейNOP там, где я подсмотрел этот функционал не изменяется ничего связанного с именем запускаемого процесса. В процессах он как и на диске. На английском SO есть темы подобные и там предлагается менять Application ID для запущенного процесса на произвольный чтобы исключить группировку. Пока изучаю.

Comment: Хорошо, напишите ответ по итогу, интересно

Comment: @АндрейNOP пока нашёл только следующее... Процессы запущенные из EXE всегда группируются. Если переименовать исполняемый файл в *.BIN то все процессы перестают группироваться. Отсюда вопрос: без создания нового файла *.BIN возможен запуск существующего EXE в память как *.BIN?